# Procedural Assignment not supported in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vivado

I've written down this following "Design source" code (on Xilinx Vivado)
The code is written in System Verilog, and it is the Hamming 7,4 encoder

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming(7,4)

```
module eccproj(
input logic [3:0] data_in,
output logic [6:0] hamcode);


logic p1,p2,p4;
    
always @(*) begin
p1 = data_in[0] + data_in[1] + data_in[3];
p2 = data_in[0] + data_in[2] + data_in[3];
p4 = data_in[1] + data_in[2] + data_in[3];

// Input : d3 d2 d1    d0
//Output : d7 d6 d5 p4 d3 d2 d1 

assign hamcode = {data_in[3:1] , p4 , data_in[0] , p2 , p1}; // Error on this line

end

endmodule
```

I am getting error in the line with the comment, and the error reads as follows :

> *[Synth 8-27] procedural assign not supported*

I know that, in Verilog the above assignment works, but how to work it using System Verilog.

- **The above error line, must concatenate the input bits and parity bits at their corresponding positions***

It would be great if someone could suggest a way to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unusual to use `assign` within an `always` block.  You likely want to have the `assign` outside the `always` block to make your synthesis tool happy.

```
always @(*) begin
    p1 = data_in[0] + data_in[1] + data_in[3];
    p2 = data_in[0] + data_in[2] + data_in[3];
    p4 = data_in[1] + data_in[2] + data_in[3];

    // Input : d3 d2 d1    d0
    //Output : d7 d6 d5 p4 d3 d2 d1 
end

assign hamcode = {data_in[3:1] , p4 , data_in[0] , p2 , p1};
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `assign` keyword inside a combinational block

```
module eccproj(
input logic [3:0] data_in,
output logic [6:0] hamcode);


logic p1,p2,p4;
    
always_comb begin
  p1 = data_in[0] + data_in[1] + data_in[3];
  p2 = data_in[0] + data_in[2] + data_in[3];
  p4 = data_in[1] + data_in[2] + data_in[3];

  // Input : d3 d2 d1    d0
  //Output : d7 d6 d5 p4 d3 d2 d1 
  
  hamcode = {data_in[3:1] , p4 , data_in[0] , p2 , p1}; 
end

endmodule
```